# JBOSS FUSE - Community Version

Tags: jbossfuse, fuseesb

I am exploring the possibility of using the community version of FUSE ESB in a production system for a period of one year.  Is it possible?  Can you please provide some advice here?

Just like RHEL, can I continue to use RedHat Jboss FUSE in production environment free of cost, without availing the support?  If I understand correctly, the subscription is for support.

Comment: why is it down voted ?

Comment: I inadvertently upvoted it and then wanted to level it back to zero, but it then down votes it... its now locked at -1  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 2):

Have your legal team review the agreement. My understanding matches yours. There are no technical limiting factors (no registration keys, etc), and Fuse is free to use the software for development purposes, but production usage requires a subscription.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is correct.  The entitlement is for support, not product usage.

Comment: http://developers.redhat.com/products/fuse/download/   -- it says like this To download JBoss Fuse you must have an account and accept the terms and conditions of the Red Hat Developer Program which provides no-cost subscriptions for development use only.

Comment: I work for Red Hat as a middleware support engineer (JBoss and Fuse).   You can use Fuse in production without an entitlement.  You won't be able to access the knowledge base articles or open a support case without an entitlement.

Comment: Doug- Check out paragraph 3

Comment: the discussion here https://developer.jboss.org/thread/235637?_sscc=t implies that the subscription/agreement applies to the *compiled binaries* offered by that download page. I think you are free to compile the "community" version on your own and use it without limitation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can find Red Hat documentation that supports both positions.  As stated, I do engineering support for Red Hat.  I asked about this at our team meeting this morning.  Unanimously, the answer was "you don't need a subscription to use the code, the subscription just gets you access to updates, the knowledge base,  etc.".  Looking at the  terms and conditions on developer.redhat.com, however, they do list "no production use without a subscription".